# Exporting a Google Sheet into an Excel using Google script

Tags: excel, google-sheets-api

I am trying to automate a backup of a google sheet into an excel.

After trying different scripts seen here and there on Stackoverflow, the one I have is now running but nothing is happening.

Any ideas?

Here is the code:

```
function exportAsxlsx() {
  var spreadsheet   = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var spreadsheetId = spreadsheet.getId()
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheetId)

  var url           = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+spreadsheetId+'/export?format=xlsx';
  var token         = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var response      = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
    }
  });

  var blobs   = response.getBlob();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('Exports');
  if(folder.hasNext()) {
    var existingPlan1 = DriveApp.getFilesByName('newfile.xlsx');
    if(existingPlan1.hasNext()){
      var existingPlan2 = existingPlan1.next();
      var existingPlanID = existingPlan2.getId();
      Drive.Files.remove(existingPlanID);
    }
  } else {
    folder = DriveApp.createFolder('BackUp');
  }
  folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('BackUp').next();
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss");
  var name = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName() + " Copy " + formattedDate;
  folder.createFile(blobs).setName(name + '.xlsx')
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the detail information about ``I have is now running but nothing is happening.``?

Comment: So, I have no more bugs, as I struggled for some time with the export line. Once I run the code, I do not have any folder being created or the copy of the google sheet created.

Comment: so it seems that the problem came from the creation of the back up folder. I have added this line to create create the file in a folder already created  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID of the folder");

Comment: In your situation, there are no errors and no creation files and folders. I could understand your situation like that. So for example, when ``DriveApp.createFile(blobs)`` is put just after ``var blobs   = response.getBlob();``, was the file created?

Answer (score 1):

So, here is a script that works:

```
function exportAsxlsx() {
  var spreadsheet   = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var spreadsheetId = spreadsheet.getId()
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheetId)

  var url           = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+spreadsheetId+'/export?format=xlsx';
  var token         = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var response      = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
    }
  });

  var blobs   = response.getBlob();
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss");
  var name = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName() + " Copy " + formattedDate;
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("your folder ID");
  folder.createFile(blobs).setName(name + '.xlsx');
}
```